# How to use <%= request.getAttribute("JsData")%> syntax in Facelets?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I just started learning about JSF. 
In JSP file we can use `<%= request.getAttribute("JsData")%>` to get the session data.
How can we get the session data in a Facelets file? For example:

```
<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var query = jQuery.noConflict();
    function getInitData() {
              getJSData();
        }
    //]]>
    <%= request.getAttribute("JsData")%>
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body onload="initData();">
<p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="login" ></p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton id="close" value="close" ></p:commandButton>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow! In the future questions, please invent a more smart title. I've edited it for you. Please also don't add tags which are not relevant to the problem. You would have exactly the same problem when you did not use jQuery, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSP *scriptlets* are indeed fortunately not supported at all in Facelets. Just use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), like as they introduced over a decade ago in JSP to replace *scriptlets*.

```html
#{JsData}
```

This kind of data is in JSF normally to be prepared and served by some managed bean. E.g.

```html
#{someBean.jsData}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `request.getAttribute()` does not return session scoped data, it returns request scoped data.